# How to preserve files downloaded by pip after failed installation?

Tags: python, pip

If `pip install a_package` fails (e.g. `pip install matplotlib` in `setuptools` isn't new enough), the next invokation of `pip install my_package` causes the file to be downloaded again instead of just comparing a checksum of the downloaded file and the remote version). How can this be prevent (assuming that `pip` has those capabilities)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a copy of `pip` to test it, but would the `--download-cache <dir>` option be of any help? From what I can tell in the docs, it will save downloaded files there, and use them.

**EDIT**
I installed `pip`, and I found a package that failed to install, and I tried to install it with `--download-cache <dir>`. I then re-ran the install, and in the log it said that it was using the cache dir, as opposed to downloading it. So **it does work**.

Comment: You're right, strange that it doesn't do it by default, creating an alias in `~/.bashrc`, e.g. `alias sip='sudo pip install --download-cache /tmp/pip-cache'`, is an alterative

Answer (score 2):

Starting in version 6.0, `pip` now handles its own caching: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#caching

> Starting with v6.0, pip provides an on by default cache which functions similarly to that of a web browser. While the cache is on by default and is designed do the right thing by default you can disable the cache and always access PyPI by utilizing the `--no-cache-dir` option.